# All failure and censoring times must be greater than zero

Tags: python, reliability

when I run code `Fit_Everything(failures=list(df['T']))`
I get Error "All failure and censoring times must be greater than zero" how can I fix this Error? "T" is temperature and has some negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Author of the Python reliability library here.
You get this error because you have values below 0 in your dataset. Unless you're fitting a Normal or Gumbel distribution then all the other supported distributions that Fit_Everything tries to fit are in the positive domain only so you'll need to remove negative values before fitting.
This can be easily done in pandas as shown by this answer:
[Remove rows of zeros from a Pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067054/remove-rows-of-zeros-from-a-pandas-series#32067092)

Note that zeros are automatically removed and a warning is printed while negative values will raise a ValueError.

If removing data isn't feasible, your other option is to adjust your data so it is all positive. Since you're working with temperature you could convert to Kelvin.